# mysql select rows for a single process

Tags: mysql, transactions

The logic I need to implement is such, that I need rows to be selected and updated only by a single process.
There can be a situation where multiple processes retrieve same rows simultaneously.

So I thought it ought to be a transaction that sets a flag of inaccessibility. But when doing it in a transaction, other processes can query those rows and do the same update after waiting for the commit of that transaction.

I need other processes to discontinue when they encounter locked rows, is there a way to do that?

Obviously, I'm no expert in mysql, so there may be another approach to accomplish my task.

Thanks in advance.

UPD: InnoDB is used.

Comment: Seems like you want to lock the whole table(s), otherwise it's likely you're going to have a deadlock hell. It still makes sense to explain the whole story so that we could provide a context-specific advice (otherwise it's an XY-problem)

Comment: Thank you already, I can switch over to MyISAM, but preferred to use InnoDB.
The whole story is that I have a table of requests and multiple processes get them and update them at time I have no control over. It is crucial to prevent the same request to be processed multiple times.

Comment: That's why one should not use RDBMS as a replacement for queue manager. What you have control over?

Comment: The table of request.
queue manager - can you be more specific?

Comment: So you can only modify the table at all? Managers == something, that can handle queues properly. eg: rabbitmq

Comment: If I understand you well I think you want to make sure that nobody will be able to update the table with outdated data.  Eg: User B loads data xyz, User A loads data xyz, User A start transaction and change xyz to abc.  Transactions ends, User B changes xyz (outdated) to 123.  If that is right, maybe a SELECT FOR UPDATE could do the job.